# adding column description on hover in Power Bi

Tags: powerbi

When I hover over a column in my report, it displays the column's name, as shown in the screenshot attached. I want to see the column description when I hover over the column; how can I do it?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a measure for each column description you want to show, like this:

```
Measure1 = "Column1 Description"
```

Then, Insert a button, and set its [Action Type] to "Page Navigation", and set the [Destination] to "None", and place this button on top the column where you want to hover.

In the formatting option of the button, open the [Style] list, and change [State] to be "On hover".

Lastly, go to [Tooltip] which is under the [Action] list, select the [fx] icon which is for conditional formatting, and select the measure you created in the first step.

Now, when you hover over the column, it should display the description as you specified.